# Fetch the Date from a String using Regex

Tags: java, regex

i need an regular expression to extract only the date from this kind of strings, regex to be used in java.

- Friendlies : International U17 W - 16/04/2014
- Japan : J2-League - 20/04/2014
- 2014 FIFA WORLD CUP IN BRAZIL - 12/06/2014

anyone can help???

Comment: You can use `\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d{4}` but it will also parse the `99/99/9999` as a date!

Comment: Why don't you try yourself?

Comment: @SabujHassan in this way i select the date...i want to select the resto of the string. im using replaceAll("REGEX","") in this way i get back only the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above(that you do not bother about the date's validness), Here is what you are looking for:

```
String str = "Friendlies : International U17 W - 16/04/2014";
str = str.replaceAll(".*(\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d{4}).*", "$1");
System.out.println(str);
```

In this example, the code is capturing the date using the group `(...)` and replacing the whole string with the captured group, which ensures to have the date.

But, a better approach will be:

```
String str = "Friendlies : International U17 W - 16/04/2014";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d{4})");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```